# What to do about a flowering currant covered with white disease or fungus?

Tags: diseases, shrubs, soft-fruit, currant

[image]Does anyone know what this is and how to deal with it please (I am in the UK)?  Are there any precautions I need to take if I just remove the whole shrub?  It is a flowering currant.  Thanks

[image: diseased flowering currant]

Answer (score 1):

[image: I hope I've done enough to end this infestation!]

In the end my only practical option.  I hope I've done enough to deal with this now!

Comment: for the most part you created a nice open plant.  Make sure you remove any crossing branches, branches that cross each other.  You want to create an open V shape plant.  This will allow more air to circulate around the plant and cut down on disease.   In the picture, the left side of the plant shows a very strong branch with many multiple coming off of it in a clump.  You may need to thin that out some.  Then in the back.  Any branches touching or almost touching the house should be removed.  Air will not be able to get between this area.  Brick will hold moisture.

Answer (score 0):

I can't magnify the photo well enough to examine the white patches in close up, but most likely its a scale infestation. You can rub it off the woody parts with a damp cloth, scrubbing as hard as you like, but on the leaves, you'd need to be much more gentle. This looks like a heavy infestation, and you might want to consider removing the shrub and choosing a different plant, because it's difficult to completely eradicate scale once it's this bad, see here https://www.rhs.org.uk/advice/profile?pid=926

Comment: The white spots on the trunk sure look like scale.  I don't think removing it is an answer.  The scale will just attack the new plants or another plant.  What about Neem?  There is no such thing as eradication you know this.  Just control. Need another picture close up for sure.  Are there scale 'predators'?  My goodness, I've fallen in love with fly predators and spider mite predators!! WOW.

Comment: Such a healthy shrub!  Too easy to spray with Neem including the top of the soil, done at night.  Right?  A few times?  I would not take this shrub out just because of scale...

Comment: Thanks for the advice!  I will try to take a closer look and maybe try to post another photo.  I was reluctant to prune in case I start spreading whatever it is but it sounds like that will not be an issue

Comment: I have added a photo above with a much closer view.  When touching the white stuff (with a glove) many very very fine cobweb like fibres stretch away from it affixed to the glove.

Comment: without doubt,a heavy scale infestation...

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Comment: Disappointing ; I grew many fruits around the house in IL and red currants were the only one that was trouble free and required no care.